# Что можно писать, кроме консольных приложений на С++?

Tags: unix, c, c++, linux

Желательно под юникс. В какую сторону посмотреть? (Только не Qt - не понравился.)
Что сейчас востребовано?

Comment: Вы хотели сказать с помощью чего?

Comment: ну да.
плюс интересна востребованность программистов со знанием той или иной библиотеки

Comment: Что можно написать на C?  Да что в голову придет (например, еще один интерпретатор Лиспа с эффективной JIT компиляцией в native).

Comment: Я понимаю, что все можно написать. ) Но ведь не на чистом стандартном си, нужно что-то еще?! Или можно написать все что угодно, имея только gcc?!

Comment: Да, имея **только** gcc можно написать все, что позволяет выполнить ядро ОС.

Comment: Не страдайте ерундой и пишите на Python + Qt. И да Qt для C++ единственная адекватная либа из тех что я видел. С ней на C++ можно хоть как-то писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gtk+

Comment: А GTK разве не на C со своей объектной оберткой?

Comment: Чистый GTK+ как раз на Си своей обёрткой, но там ничего сложного. Можно попробовать PyGTK, если Python знаете.

Comment: Я к тому, что в Linux C++ как-то не особо распространен, единственный, кто сейчас активно продвигает его, - это Microsoft, оно и понятно: все продукты на C++ написаны, что для активных Unix компаний, то там C++ тока как дополнительное предложение, вспомните на чем основные серьезные DB написаны, про ядра unix вообще молчу.

Comment: gtk+ создан для программирования в чистом С.
1. ничто не мешает в С++ программах писать части в стиле Сю
2. есть обертка для С++. называется gtkmm.

Answer (score 2):

[GTK](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/)

Comment: GTK востребован сильно? Сам на нём пишу один проект... но в вакансиях вообще не видел почти (1-2 максимум), что нужны знания GTK+.

Comment: Пишите под Линукс?

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть в сторону Boost.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос задан классно :-) Я б рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону [U++](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate%2B%2B)